# Firebase analytics is not working in production mode apk flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

During the debug mode of my flutter app, firebase analytics is working ie capture the user interaction of the app. But when i build the final apk of my app for production, firebase analytics is not working.

Please help. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Material App NavigatorObservers add this check

```
FirebaseAnalytics _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver getAnalyticsObserver() =>
          FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: _analytics);
    
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyAppHome(),
      navigatorObservers: [
       if (kReleaseMode) locator<AnalyticsService>().getAnalyticsObserver(),
      ],
    );
```